Get 2nd most recent value of a related record in Archer
I would like to retrieve the 2nd most recent value in Archer.
I have an application “A” whose records contain “Previous” and “Current” fields, with mapped assessment records (from application “B”).
The “Current” fields should fetch their values from the most recent (and status = reviewed) assessment record that is mapped to the record in application A. On the other hand, “Previous” fields should fetch the reviewed assessment record before the most recent reviewed assessment record. For example, if record-A has mapped B1 (Status = Reviewed) B2 (Draft) & B3 (Reviewed), then the Current fields should fetch their values from B3 while the Previous fields should fetch their values from B1.
Any suggestions on the formula I can use for the Previous ratings?
Still new to the platform so I was only able to get the Current fields using mostrecentvalue. Help is much appreciated!
